# Simple division

Tags: c#, .net

I must be doing something dumb:

```
float ans = (i/3);
```

So why when `i = 7` is ans coming out at 2.0?

`i` is an int

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because the [/ operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx) is performing an integer division if both operands are integers. You could do this:

```
float ans = (i / 3.0f);
```

Comment: Bonus +1 for linking to appropriate MSDN page.

Comment: Many thanks for that - but why does "f" make the number different?

Comment: @m.edmondson: Numeric suffixes are hints to the compiler that a literal number should be treated as a certain type. It's shorthand for `(float)3.0`

Answer (score 6):

You need to make one of the operands a float, otherwise the calculation is done with integers *first* (which always results in an integer), before converting the result to a float.

```
float ans = ((float) i) / 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's doing integer division because `i` is an `int` and `3` is an `int`. Try this:

```
float ans = ((float)i/3.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `float ans = (i / 3.0)` or `float ans = (i / 3f)` or `float ans = ((float)i / 3)`. `/` does an integer division if both sides are of type integer.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: in C#, int / int = int.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```
float ans = ((float)i/3);
```

Otherwise you're taking two integers and dividing them to find the number of whole times the divisor goes in to the dividend. (As mentioned, an int/int=int regardless of the destination type. And, to the compiler, "3" is another integer (unless you specify it as `3.0f`))

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have this in a loop of some sort. You could specify your i variable as a float instead.

```
for (float i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   float ans = (i/3);
   // statements
}
```

Just another solution.