# Calculate Pecentage in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585166/simple-division)

I juz wanna ask how to represent this kind of math expression in C#

**a/b*100.0**

i try doing this. but it does not work as the percentage display this kind of value (19) not (19.00);

```
int gradeA;
int students;
int percentage;


percentage = (gradeA/students*100.0);

percentLabel.Text=Convert.ToString(percentage);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        //you want the values as a floating point:
        double gradeA;
        double students;
        //ToString("P") displays the value as a percentage (e.g. 19%)
        percentLabel.Text = (gradeA / students).ToString("P");
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because your values are `integers` and you need a `float`.

Try:

```
float percentage;

percentage = ((float)(gradeA/students))*100.0);

percentLabel.Text = String.Format("{0.00}", percentage);
```